# Why is docstrip putting extra macro calls in a hyperlink inside a footnote that has a tilde?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, tilde

Here's a minimal example of Docstrip putting extra macro bits into a `\href` call inside a footnote when the URL has a tilde:

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{foo.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi

% \title{The foo package\thanks{This document corresponds to
%     foo version, dated date.}}
%
% \author{The Author\thanks{Author's website with bad link:
%     \href{http://example.com/~user/} {foo}. Working link:
%     \href{http://example.com/user}{foo}} }
%
% \maketitle
%
% \section{Introduction}
%
% a link that works: \href{http://example.com/~user}
%     {foo}.
```

In the resulting PDF, the tilde in the URL in the footnote has some TeX macros in it you get:

```
http://example.com/\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}user/
```

so something is wrong with the tilde. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\href` and friends have to do some magic to make special characters like `#` or `~` work. This magic works only if the commands are used outside of any other commands. But the `hyperref` package accepts “escaped” versions as well: `\#`, `\~` and so on. They work in any case and are a bit easier to remember than commands like `\textasciitilde`.

This is actually independent of `docstrip`, the following example exhibits the same behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Test}
\author{Me\footnote{\url{http://example.com/~}}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\url{http://example.com/~}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I have to admit that I have no idea why this is happening.  However, replacing the literal tilde with `\textasciitilde` will fix your problem.

```
% \author{The Author\thanks{Author's website with bad link:
%     \href{http://example.com/\textasciitilde user/}{foo}. Working link:
%     \href{http://example.com/user}{foo}} }
```