# URL with tilde character?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls, links, tilde

I'm trying to make a URL with a tilde character (`~`) in it:

```
\usepackage{url}
...
\url{http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws}
```

It looks right in the resulting PDF, but when clicking on it the browser goes to a wrong URL: `http://lyle.smu.edu/%18tspell/jaws`

If I type in the browser `%7e` (escape code for '`~`') instead of `%18` the browser then goes to the correct URL.

Any idea how to get a correct link in the PDF?

Comment: Duplicate? See these questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312/correctly-typesetting-a-tilde

Comment: @MartinTapankov: I don't think its a duplicate of theses questions. It's about the tilde in an URL, i.e. more like verbatim, then producing the the tilde symbol. However, this post is very similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5260/2975

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should use the `hyperref` package (which uses `url` internally but improves on it). It will not only format the link but also place a real hyperlink into the PDF. With `url` alone the link is only normal text, but is probably recognized as hyperlink by your PDF viewer, but with the wrong code for `~`. LaTeX tends to substitute the code of these special characters depending on the font you use instead of taking the ASCII code.

This works fine with Acrobat Reader:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws}
\end{document}
```

A funny thing is that `%18` is the ASCII code for "CAN (cancel)", which doesn't make much sense and `\char"18` isn't the tilde in the `tt` font. I can't follow how this specific code was produced.

Comment: Wow, this is one great package! (and it solved the problem too - thanks).

Comment: @Hagai Cibulski Be careful with hyperref: it is temperamental, as a search of this site will reveal. It likes being the last package loaded (apart from packages that need loading after it)...

Comment: I think that the problem is the hyperref changes the definition of things, (like chapter and section and toc and cite entries) by adding a link to them, this will fail if you load another package that changes the way these command are defined.

Comment: I suspect that heperref is now causing errors in IEEE PDF eXpress, which doesn't like bookmarks

Comment: @Hagai: in this case use `hyperref` s `\nolinkurl` macro, and disable the PDF bookmarks.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I took your MWE, compiled it with MiKTeX 2.9, opened the pdf with Adobe Reader 11, clicked the link, which was opened in FF 19, but it tried to open `http://lyle.smu.edu/%257Etspell/jaws` (`%257E` is `~` encoded twice, i.e. `%` in `%7E` (`~`) encoded into `%25`). SumatraPDF and PDF-X Change Viewer opened the correct link in FF, so it might even be a bug / undesirable behavior on the side of Adobe Reader? Any idea if we can work around this?

Comment: @doncherry: Not really, but I will have a look at it.

Comment: Oddly enough, `\url{link}` typesets with a different font than `\href{link}{link}`.

Answer (score 11):

The `~` character will work fine if used inside `\url{}` or `\hyperref{}` within your text because they automatically disable all the TeX parsing; as described by 
Martin Scharrer. The same is true for other characters like `_` and for the `\path{}` command provided by the `url` package.

**But** if you have a URL within your bibliography’s `.bib` file it won’t work. The solution to this problem is to [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the character. The tilde would be encoded as `%7E`. The bibliography entry would look like this:

```
@article{Spell.2009,
  author = {Spell, Brett},
  date   = {2009-12-24},
  title  = {Java API for WordNet Searching (JAWS)},
  url    = {http://lyle.smu.edu/%7Etspell/jaws/},
}
```

This will compile correctly and the URL is clickable in e.g. generated PDF. You can even just copy that URL into your browser, it will load as expected.

Comment: In my experience `~` works fine in the `url` field in `.bib` files. Ultimately it will depend on the style you are using, but most styles that support a `url` field usually use `hyperref`/`url` to typeset the URLs and then `~` is supported out of the box. Some styles use fallback definitions in case `url`/`hyperref` commands are not loaded (not available), in that case `~` may not come out as expected, though I would expect `%7E` even worse in those situations.

Answer (score 11):

This did it for me (plus: the link works!)

```
\string~
```

From: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3663

Comment: This worked inside author footnote, i.e. `\author{\thanks{\url{~}}}`. Other answers did not.

Answer (score 7):

uses `\%7E` to replace `~`, do not forget `\` before `%7E`.

```
url    = {http://lyle.smu.edu/\%7Etspell/jaws/},
```