# How to print '~' character using latex

Tags: symbols, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL with tilde character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/url-with-tilde-character)

I tried `\~`, which doesn't work; the ~ will appear on top of the following letter. `~` will print nothing but an empty spot. What I want is to print a website link like www.website.com/~aname in my document using LaTeX.

How can I do it? Google didn't give me an answer.

Comment: ...also see [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/5764)

Answer (score 6):

For typing URLs, you should import the `url` package:

```
\usepackage{url}
```

and then use the `\url` macro:

```
\url{www.website.com/~aname}
```

This will take care of all the details. Moreover, if you also use the `hyperref` package, you will get a nice clickable link in the resulting PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\~{}
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Print_version

However this will place the ~ higher up (as though it were above a letter that isn't there). A more elegant solution would be: $\sim$.