# Citing webpage with ~ in address

Tags: citing, urls

Here is the exact webpage I want to cite:

```
    \bibitem{BrouwerSRG}A. Brouwer.
    Strongly Regular Graphs table
    http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab1-50.html
    \filbreak
```

Now, if I type this in and compile, the `~` does not show up at all.  A professor recommended using `$\sim$aeb` and then later said he was mistaken to use that and instead I should use `\~{}aeb`.  When I use `$\sim$aeb`, it seems to look correct, though perhaps the `~` is a little big.  If I use `\~{}aeb`, it does not look right at all, it looks like a superscript `~`.  If I do `\~aeb` only, it puts the `~` above the `a`, so definitely not right.

I don't know much about bibliographies, but I'm just using `\begin{thebibliography}{45}` to start up my references, in case that matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `\url` from the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) or the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package.

Comment: Duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/url-with-tilde-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `\url` command from the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, the tilde works without having to modify the URL. It becomes clickable, too, if you compile with `pdflatex`.

In LaTeX, `~` just means "non-breakable space". No line break is allowed between words that are connected with a tilde.

Have you considered using `bibtex` or `biblatex` for your bibliography? This will make sure that references are formatted consistently, and the reference style can be changed without having to reformat the entire bibliography.

Comment: If I add in the line to use the hyperref package, and do nothing else at all, now my file errors out.

Comment: @Graphth: Could you try the `url` package? If the error persists, please post a new question.