# Add a hyperlink in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

It's cool to add a hyperlink in references like this:
[image]

I want to know how to add the blue box in bibtex. For example, the following article's link is "ee".

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/osdi/DeanG04,
author    = {Jeffrey Dean and
           Sanjay Ghemawat},
title     = {MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters},
booktitle = {OSDI},
year      = {2004},
ee        = {http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html},
crossref  = {DBLP:conf/osdi/2004},
bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Loading the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) package and using

```
url        = {http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html},
```

gives a clickable `url` in your bibliography.

[image: screenshot]

alternatively you can use

```
             note        = {\href{http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html}{my text for the link which can break across lines}},
```

which gives a link which has different text from the link. I agree with @Mico- this is probably a bad idea in general for a variety of different reasons.

[image: screensh]

Complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @inproceedings{dblp,
             author = {Jeffrey Dean and
             Sanjay Ghemawat},
             title     = {MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters},
             booktitle = {OSDI},
             year      = {2004},
             note        = {\href{http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html}{my text for the link which can break across lines}},
             bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
             }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}   % bibliography
\usepackage{hyperref}

% bibliography
\bibliography{mybib}
\begin{document}

hello world \cite{dblp}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: ,this is a solution, but I'm wondering if this url can be hidden in paper's title. Paper's title is clickable.

Comment: @LijieXu - Unless you can be absolutely certain that your paper will always be read on-screen, and never from a paper copy, it's probably not a good idea to hide the actual URL from your readers' eyes.

Comment: @LijieXu see the update :)

Comment: Note that if you [have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252471/what-is-the-use-of-tilde-in-url) *tilde* `~` in `\href` it won't work. To fix it, you [can](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/url-with-tilde-character) replace `~` with `%7E`. BTW: interesting [point of view](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/tilde.html) *why the `%7e` solution really good?*.

Comment: Note for future readers: Using hyperref with `\url{....}` can also solve issues related to underscores and tildes in urls.

Comment: @cmhughes the command \href{}{} does not work in the bibtex file. How can I activate it?

Comment: @Mico Most documents come in an electronic format now and hidden clickable links seem to be fine to me. If you read a hard-copy without a computer around, then having the explicit link is not really helpful. If you read a hard-copy with a computer around, get the electronic version and click on the link. Bottom-line: explicit human-unreadable links are not useful. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pluton - It depends on what's shown and on what's hidden. My interpretation of the OP's request was that the information that would be shown might not to be sufficient to let a reader of a hardcopy version of the publication find the bibliographic reference without considerable sleuthing.

Comment: I find href better as I just show the DOI, not the doi.org URL, while linking. Same for PMID. Nobody wants to type the entire doi URL if reading the hard copy, I agree with @pluton . You will instead type it in a search engine, namely doi.org's.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks for the code of @cmhughe. I rewrite it as follows:

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/osdi/DeanG04,
author    = {Jeffrey Dean and
           Sanjay Ghemawat},
title     = {\href{http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html}{MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters}},
booktitle = {OSDI},
year      = {2004},
ee        = {http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/dean.html},
crossref  = {DBLP:conf/osdi/2004},
bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
```

In this way, the hyperlink effect can be achieved.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. You can add the entry automatically using BibTool and `bibtool --  'add.field{title2="\href{%s(url)}{%s(title)}"}' test.bib -o test1.bib`. See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329318/hide-hyperlink-in-bibtex-title/330458#330458) post for details.

Comment: how to get the link in "In OSDI, 2004"?

Comment: @Lijie Xu the command \href{}{} does not work in the bibtex file. How can I activate it?

Comment: According to the official `bibtex` documentation ( https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex ), `ee` is not an accepted field for `inproceedings` . The fact that `ee` appeared in your example, confused me and might confuse other people. Please consider removing it.

Comment: I was looking for hours on how to add a website to the bibliography, and this is the unique solution that worked for me. Thanks.