# Bibtex unsrt type style that shows arxiv links?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Is it possible to use `unsrt` style for bibtex that will show arxiv links? I remember using `apsrev4-1` for one seminar before and that showed arxiv links, even combined them with hyperref so you could easily click on them in pdf. But Now when I use that I get errors (I guess it's because I'm not using `revtex` as document class).

The issue is that some articles I cited are only on arxiv, not in any journal, and `unsrt` just lists author, name of the article and the year of publishing. I'd like to also add arxiv link so that it's not empty looking.

EDIT:

I managed the look I want (sort of, I still get semi colon instead of colon, when citing multiple sources), this is the mwe that resembles the most to my original file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square,numbers,colon}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=DarkGray, citecolor=DarkGray, urlcolor=DarkGray, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, hypertexnames=false, unicode]{hyperref}


\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing

\hypersetup{linkcolor=DarkGray}


\begin{document}

This is an example \cite{Anninos:2008fx}\cite{Arnowitt:1962hi}\cite{Banados:1992gq,Bardeen:1999px}


And another \cite{Bekenstein73,Cardy1,Cardy2}\cite{lrr-2004-1,de1998lie}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography is badly stretched, and in my original file (which I won't post here since its preamble is massive alone) I get this:

[image]

The last reference even goes out of bounds :S

EDIT2:

This did it:

```
\begingroup
\raggedright
\sloppy
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{mybib}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Ok, so the error I got from using `apsrev` is because I needed to delete all .bbl .aux etc files when compiling. Now I get arxiv links, but my citations are [Surname(Year)] not [Number] type :\

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `unsrt` bibliography style -- which is well more than 20 years old and thus (unsurprisingly, in my view) lacks any awareness of what to do with electronic record fields such as `url`, `doi`, and `eid` -- I would recommend you use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style, which *does* know what to do with fields such as `doi` (short for digital object identifier). See also http://arxiv.org/help/jref for suggestions on how to provide doi-related information for arxiv-published papers.

The `unsrtnat` bibliography style can be used independently of the `natbib` package.

Comment: Still not showing the arxiv links and I've lost numbered citations like [1]... It would show them if I put URL, but I'm copying bibtex references from inspirehep, and they have them sorted out that way...

Comment: @dingo_d - Please edit your posting to show an actual example of a bib entry that's generated by inspirehep.

Comment: I sorted my problem out, sort of. I used `apsrev4-1` style with natbib's `\setcitestyle{square,numbers}`, so I got [Number] style. But now the citations are poorly aligned, and are overflowing out of page. I'll create mwe asap.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `unsrt` is perfectly compatible with adding hyperlinks (or links) in bibtex. See the accepted answer's "alternative" solution here: [Add a hyperlink in bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100782/add-a-hyperlink-in-bibtex)

In short, use

> note = {\href{link}{text}}

in your .bib entry.