# How can I use hyper reference command in Latex?

Tags: hyperref

In LaTeX, I want to refer any article by using `\cite{name}` successfully. Now I want to cite the same article in my paper and also the citation is hyperlink with the original document. I tried with command `\hyperref{}` but not successful. Can anyone plz tell me to do so? Thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100782/add-a-hyperlink-in-bibtex