# BiBTeX: Enabling Clickable Hyperlinks in References

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I'm currently utilizing BiBTeX with the bibliography style 'unsrt'. In the 'references.bib' file, a reference could appear as follows:

```
@article{ATLAS:2012yve,
    author = "Aad, Georges and others",
    collaboration = "ATLAS",
    title = "{Observation of a new particle in the search for the Standard Model Higgs boson with the ATLAS detector at the LHC}",
    eprint = "1207.7214",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "hep-ex",
    reportNumber = "CERN-PH-EP-2012-218",
    doi = "10.1016/j.physletb.2012.08.020",
    journal = "Phys. Lett. B",
    volume = "716",
    pages = "1--29",
    year = "2012"
}
```

I'm aiming to have the arXiv number and journal name as clickable hyperlinks, just like the example shown in the attached image.[image] Are there any available methods, such as adding specific codes before `\begin{document}` or modifying the `.bst` file or using `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`, without requiring modification of each individual reference like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100800/149108), that could help me achieve this?

Is it also possible to have different hyperlink colors for the arXiv link and the DOI link?

Comment: unsrt is too old. You can naturally try to change it, but it would be better to use a newer style or to switch to biblatex/biber.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer
Thank you for your comment. Could you kindly suggest a new bibliography style that I can utilize everywhere without encountering any issues?

Comment: I would use biblatex + biber.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have followed the suggestion provided in this link (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51439). However, I encountered an issue where the DOI is displayed explicitly instead of having the journal details as clickable hyperlinks. Is there a possibility to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Try using the bibliography style apsrev4-2 together with the hyperref package.  That should get the hyperlinks you want.  You'll see plenty of examples of this in the hep-ph and other section of arXiv.org, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.02521

Answer (score 0):

The main question is, given bibfile entries of the form shown in the question, how to get clickable links for both the journal and arXiv versions of the cited articles.  A notable feature of the bibfile entry is that it contains fields that are not the standard ones, as documented in the LaTeX Companion for example.  It contains fields for information on the e-print version of the paper, and for a collaboration name.  So typical bibiliography styles don't support what's asked for.

The format of the bibfile entry is in fact that given by the [INSPIRE](https://inspirehep.net/) database for literature in high-energy physics, thereby giving a standard for that area of science. So  one should look for a solution in the files provided by the journals that specialize in high-energy physics and use the requested style of citation.

Possible solutions include

1. Use the `revtex4-2` document class (which is available on CTAN, and is in the TeXLive and MiKTeX distributions) together with the hyperref package:

   ```
   \documentclass{revtex4-2}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \begin{document}
   \cite{ATLAS:2012yve}
   \bibliography{tmp}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This assumes that there is a file `tmp.bib` containing the given entry.      The resulting citation is[image: Formatted citation]
   It has the requested two links, and shows information about both the    e-print and the collaboration name.  The hyperlink to the journal version uses the DOI information in the bibfile entry.

   The citation is not exactly in the form that the OP gives in a screenshot, since the author part is written as "G. Aad et al. (ATLAS)" instead of "ATLAS Collaboration".  I would not worry about changing that.
2. Similarly use class and/or style files plus the .bst file provided by some other journal, e.g., [files for JHEP](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp).  (Those files are not, unfortunately, on CTAN or in TeXLive or MiKTeX.)
3. If for some reason, the class or style files from a journal don't give the desired formatting of the whole document, then one can just use the .bst file from one of the journals.  The simplest is to use `JHEP.bst` from [files for JHEP](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \bibliographystyle{JHEP}
   \begin{document}
   \cite{ATLAS:2012yve}
   \bibliography{tmp}
   \end{document}
   ```
4. If changes are needed for the formatting of the citations compared with what's provided by the available .bst files, one can always make a modified .bst file.  That's the obvious thing to do to get differently colored hyperlinks for the journal and arXiv.