# How to deal with a tilde in url's in Mendeley?

Tags: biblatex, pdftex

If a link in an url contains `~`, Mendeley changes it to `$\sim$` and `hyperref` links just don't work. I use pdflatex and biblatex. 
Is there a quick way how to change manually the link in Mendeley to fix this? Editing manually the `library.bib` file exported by Mendeley is not an option for me.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10858/17423

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely something you need to address on a Mendeley level, the software needs to make sure it exports correct `.bib` files, and `http://example.edu/$\sim$elk/bronto.pdf` is hardly correct. URLs should be exported verbose without any modifications.

But with Biber's sourcemapping we can try and save your file, let's say you have

```
@online{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
  url     = {http://example.edu/$\sim$elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-09-07},
}
```

Then

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url,
            match=\regexp{\$\\sim\$},
            replace=\regexp{\~}]
    }
  }
}
```

will turn that `$\sim$` back into a `~`.

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{bronto,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972-11-16},
  url     = {http://example.edu/$\sim$elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-09-07},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url,
            match=\regexp{\$\\sim\$},
            replace=\regexp{\~}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{bronto}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output with correct URL]

Answer (score 0):

So, one simply has to replace in the url in Mendeley `~` with `\textasciitilde{}`. Then it works. Note that I have the option "do not escape latex special characters" in Mendeley.

Comment: Actually, you should just be able to load the `hyperref` package in your document. If there's a way to just make Mendeley not do anything with `~`, that'd be best.

Comment: It is possible to tell Mendeley not to do anything with ALL special characters in all fields. But not separately in the `url` field. That's the problem.

Comment: And people wonder why I prefer to write my documents straight-up… It sucks when the tool is your problem.

Comment: @SeanAllred I got enchanted by sever features of Mendeley that I really like. That might have been a mistake.

Comment: What other special characters need special treatment? If it's just generic Unicode stuff, use `biber`/`biblatex`.