# Ampersand in Biber Sourcemap

Tags: biblatex, biber, ampersand, url

I use Mendeley to create my bib-files and then `\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}` to create my citations.
As I have some URLs, I also use `DeclareSourcemap` (as suggested in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309995/65582)) to replace special characters. This works until I encountered a new case where an ampersand is in the URL.
The entry that creates the issue is (in `mybib.bib`):

```
@article{EP2014,
    author = {{European Parliament} and {European Council}},
    journal = {Official Journal of the European Union},
    number = {L173},
    pages = {349--496},
    title = {{Directive 2014/65/EU on markets in financial instruments and amending Directive 2002/92/EC and Directive 2011/61/EU}},
    url = {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014L0065{\&}from=EN},
    volume = {57},
    year = {2014}
}
```

which has a URL containing the escaped ampersand `{\&}` which needs to be `&`.

I tried using the `DeclaresourceMap` like so, but it doesnt work (biber says main.bcf is malformed)

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{ % Replaces '{\&}' with just '&'
      \step[fieldsource=url,
        match=\regexp{\{\\\&\}},
        replace=\regexp{\&}]
    }
  }
}
```

When I look in `main.bcf` it gets parsed as

```
<bcf:map_step map_field_source="url" map_match="\{\\\&\}" map_replace="\&"/>
```

which my text editor marks as an error (due to the ampersand not being properly escaped? thats at least by best guess).

### MWE:

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{ % Replaces '{\&}' with just '&'
      \step[fieldsource=url,
        match=\regexp{\{\\\&\}},
        replace=\regexp{\&}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\textcite{EP2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which I then run using either `latexmk main` or `pdflatex main` and then `biber main`.

Any idea how to solve the error and properly escape the ampersand?

### Note:

As I use Mendeley for the creation of my bib-file, I cannot change the bib-file directly, and changing the escaping of special characters when exporting from Mendeley messes up other entries, therefore I think I am bound to using `DeclareSourcemap`. If you have another option I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.bcf` file that `biblatex` uses to communicate the sourcemaps to Biber is essentially an XML file. As far as I can see XML files don't really like `&`s (https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax), so we can replace `&` with its Unicode code point `\x{26}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{ % Replaces '{\&}' with just '&'
      \step[fieldsource=url,
        match=\regexp{\{\\\x{26}\}},
        replace=\regexp{\x{26}}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{EP2014,
    author = {{European Parliament} and {European Council}},
    journal = {Official Journal of the European Union},
    number = {L173},
    pages = {349--496},
    title = {{Directive 2014/65/EU on markets in financial instruments and amending Directive 2002/92/EC and Directive 2011/61/EU}},
    url = {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014L0065{\&}from=EN},
    volume = {57},
    year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{EP2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: URL: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014L0065&from=EN.]

But really you should **complain to the Mendeley people**, the URL field is a verbatim field where characters should not be escaped at all.

Comment: Wonderful, that does it!
I know that Mendeley is -ehm- suboptimal and doesnt really work well with *TeX. But I got used to being able to search through all pdfs (not supported by zotero afaik) and open them in-app. If you have a better alternative (open-source?), I am all ears!
Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: @David Sorry, I don't know about a good alternative. I would have suggested Zotero (where [Better BibTeX](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) can help you obtain proper `.bib` files without weird quirks), but there are also more basic `.bib` file tools like JabRef, BibDesk (Mac only). I don't use any of these tools, so all I can tell you is that from time to time problems with Mendeley pop up here and there. Even if you found a work-around, you should still contact the developers and complain. I have no high hopes that they will do anything about it, but they should know...

Answer (score 1):

When using a XML configuration file for the biber tool, the answer provided by moewe can be implemented by:

```xml
<config>
  <sourcemap>
        <!-- Replace {\&} with & in URL field -->
        <map>
          <map_step map_field_source="url" map_match="\{\\\x{26}\}" map_replace="\x{26}"/>
        </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```