# Misplaced alignment tab character & in bibliography

Tags: errors, biber

TeXtudio gives me the error `Misplaced alignment tab character &.` in the line where I insert my bibliography. This line is `\include{\dir/bibliography}` which links to

```
\manualmark%
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\label{app:bibliography}

\emergencystretch=1em%
\printbibliography
```

I think the problem might be caused by `&` symbols within the references, of which there are very many. I could replace them with `\&` or "and", but maybe there's an easier solution.

I'm using MiKTeX and Biber.

Comment: Replacing `&` with `\&` in the `.bib` file is generally the easiest solution (and running Biber again afterwards). With a Replace All function in an editor this can be done very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The character `&` has a special meaning for LaTeX: It marks new table columns or new alignment columns in general (think `align`).

As such you can't generally use `&` in its meaning as ampersand character in standard LaTeX and must escape it to `\&`, see [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/35864). There are some exceptions to this rule: In `\verb|...|` and other verbatim commands as well as `\url` and some related commands you can often use `&` without escaping it, but there are some subtle points with those commands (see for example [How to use a link as footnote that has special characters inside?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13224/35864)).

It's pretty much the same for the bibliography. You should escape `&` to `\&` in `.bib` files *except* in special verbatim fields like `doi`, `eprint` and `url`.

**The best solution™ is to make sure to escape `&` to `\&` in the `.bib` file unless it is in a `doi`, `eprint`, `url` or otherwise verbatim field.** E.g. instead of

```
publisher = {Pub & Co.},
```

you should write

```
publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
```

---

If for some reason you absolutely cannot bring yourself to fix your `.bib` file once for good, you can have Biber do that on the fly for you (but this is **at most the second best solution™**). (`biblatex` uses an XML format to communicate with Biber, where `&` is also a special character, so we better escape it as `\x{26}`.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=publisher,
        match=\regexp{\x{26}},
        replace=\regexp{\\\x{26}}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date      = {1980},
  publisher = {Pub & Co.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Pub & Co." displayed as desired]

Related [Ampersand in Sourcemap for BibTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444274/35864).

Answer (score 0):

You are right. '&' has special meaning to (La)TeX, and the result of compiling a bibliography is ultimately processed by LaTeX.

There are names that include '&', like the journal "'Software -- Practice & Experience" or "John Wiley & Sons". Replacing with "and" would be wrong. Go for "\&", the (La)TeX way to type that character.