# Single bibtex entry not working, please help

Tags: bibliographies, biber

All my cites seems to be working, except this one, and *I can't figure out why* — like all of my bibliography, it's exported from Mendeley, so I don't understand it isn't working… and now I'm out of ideas, so I hope that someone can help me :)

The code with the cite is:

```
The data in the table are obtained from~\cite{John2008}.
```

The warning is:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'John2008' on page 5 undefined on input line 8.
```

This is the entry:

```
@incollection{John2008,
author = {{John, O. P., Naumann, L. P. Soto}, C. J.},
booktitle = {Handbook of personality: Theory and research},
number = {Chapter 4},
pages = {114--158},
publisher = {New York, NY: Guilford Press},
title = {{Handbook of personality: Theory and research}},
url = {https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/{~}johnlab/bigfive.htm},
year = {2008}
}
```

I tried to remove the tilde from the URL, but that didn't help.

I use Biber and the `\printbibliography`-command to print the bibliography.

Comment: You have too many commas in author name. It should be `author = {John, O. P. and Naumann, L. P.  and Soto, C. J.},`

Comment: take a look at the author field.  at the very least the braces are peculiarly placed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code are several errors:

1. authors are divided by `and`, not by a comma
2. The braces in the author field are wrong, just delete the second pair
3. delete the braces around `~` in the url

So with the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{John2008,
  author    = {John, O. P. and Naumann, L. P. and Soto, C. J.},
  booktitle = {Handbook of personality: Theory and research},
  number    = {Chapter 4},
  pages     = {114--158},
  publisher = {New York, NY: Guilford Press},
  title     = {Handbook of personality: Theory and research},
  url       = {https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~johnlab/bigfive.htm},
  year      = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authortitle,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
The data in the table are obtained from~\cite{John2008}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you get the result without errors:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new to bibtex/biblatex/biber!
With your answer I also figured out how to fix the Mendeley export: The authors should be on separate lines in the author field, and _not_ separated by a comma.
By removing the tickmark in the Mendeley setting in "Bibtex" → "Escape LaTeX special characters (#{}%& etc.)" and using the fix in [this Stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275538/24952), the URL are also formatted correctly.