# Is there a good way to write URLs with tilde without using url or hyperref packages?

Tags: urls, tilde

I want to write URLs, but the stylesheet cannot be used with url or hyperref packages. Then if I copy the urls from my pdf file and paste them to the browser, tilde symbols become %2(+a weird character which looks like o with something on it) and I cannot reach the websites. What should I do with this problem?

Comment: `%7e` is nothing but ascii tilde... On my browser it automatically becomes `~`

Comment: `%7e` is the precent encodnig ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding ) of `~`. However, does this question help you or answer your problem? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/url-with-tilde-character

Comment: @Symbol1 Sorry, I made a mistake. What I saw was different, so updated the question. However, you are right. I could write %7e directly on my draft and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Ronny Thanks, but it does not answer my question because I cannot use url or hyperref package.

Comment: You'll need to give us more details: all that `url` does is define `\url` and appropriate mechanisms to print URLs, so there's no obvious need for an alternative!

Comment: The stylesheet I am using is simply incompatible with url and hyperref. This is the only reason I posted this question.

Comment: I am not aware that package `url` conflicts with other packages. What's the problem?

Comment: @Nickel Please edit in an example: as Heiko says, it's hard to imagine a set up where `url` is not usable.

Answer (score 5):

A primitive way of writing URLs is the `\verb` command:

```
\verb|http://example.org/~user/index.html#start|
```

Of course, this does not create any link, package `hyperref` can do this.
But, some PDF viewers use a heuristics to detect links in text.

Answer (score 2):

Allows line breaking at `/`, `-`, `_` and `~` characters (more can be added).  I added `sloppypar`, since even this many breakpoints may stress the flushing algorithms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\fauxurl[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily\fauxurlhelp#1\relax\relax\egroup}
\def\fauxurlhelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx/#1#1\penalty0\else%
    \ifx-#1#1\penalty0\else%
      \ifx\_#1#1\penalty0\else%
        \ifx~#1\char"7E\penalty0\else#1%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxurlhelp#2\relax\fi}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\lipsum[4]
\fauxurl{%
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331979/is~there~a-good-way-to-write~urls-with-tilde-without-using-url-or-hyperref-packa%
}
\lipsum[2]
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]