# how to write a copyable "~" (tilde) in a link of bibliography

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I want to have a link on the pdf output of tex file such that when someone copies that and pastes it on a browser (and not by clicking on it), it works. My link has "~", so when I copy it, either nothing is instead of "~" or a wrong character is there. Hence, it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207641/120578 I think this answer makes your question a duplicate because there is an answer about this... But it is not a real question about this. So your question is a "usefull duplicate" that has to link to the answer and not to the question...

Comment: @koleygr yes, the solution there works. Thanks

Comment: @m0_as try using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`