# how to get PSTricks QR codes to handle tildes properly?

Tags: pstricks, tilde, pst-barcode

I am getting bitten by the same problem from [one of my previous questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5260/why-is-docstrip-putting-extra-macro-calls-in-a-hyperlink-inside-a-footnote-that-h): tildes are not handled properly. But now it's the PSTricks QR code package that's not working, and none of the suggestions from the other question are working. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2cm,2cm)
\psbarcode{http://example.com/~user}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

When I put the result into a QR decoder, I get

```
http://example.com/protect unhbox voidb@x penalty @M  {}user
```

...which is exactly the problem I had before. But neither `\textasciitilde` nor `\~` works; both insert weird extra bits into the file.

I can work around this instance by using a URL shortener, but really I'd like to know how to teach PSTricks the same tilde-handling magic that hyperref knows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\psbarcode{http://example.com/\string~user}{}{qrcode}`

`\string` makes the active character `~` to an inactive one.

Comment: Perfect. It also works with `#`.